# How to uncheck a check box on another check click and also set the control visibility to false

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I write the sample code to un-check a check box on another check box click. At the same time i would like to set the visibilty of control to false based on check or uncheck of check box here is what i have written

```
<form name="formName">
<input type="checkbox" name="priorityHigh"
    onclick="if(this.checked) {document.formName.priorityLow.checked=false;}">High Priority

<input type="checkbox" name="priorityLow"
    onclick="if(this.checked) {document.formName.priorityHigh.checked=false;}">Low Priority

<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"  visible=
"false">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstName" runat="server" visible=
"false">
</asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

Now assume on first check box click i will have visibility of text box1 now on second check box click i would like to uncheck the first one and set the visibility of textbox1 to false and make the second one visible to true.

Any help please

Comment: Can you show generated HTML, please, rather than the asp.net source. Javascript doesn't care what technology created the HTML.

Comment: Use a `<input type='radio'>` to only have one checked at a time, not a `<input type='checkbox'>`.

Comment: It should be working fine .... [jsFiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/sFHwq/)

Comment: @Lonesomeday : I initially write to un-check a check box on checking other that works fine now for the same i would like to have control visible to false on check or uncheck of a check box check this [link]http://raamdev.com/making-checkboxes-behave-like-radio-buttons#comment-30686

Answer (score 1):

use

`document.getElementById("txtLastName").style.visibility="hidden/visible"`

to set the visibility and

`document.getElementById("checkboxId").checked=true`

to set checkbox value or the same you did.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in JS, but I got some jQuery pointers.

First you capture the click event in jquery. Then you select all checkboxes http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/ and uncheck them. then you check the on clicked using the "this" keyword. To se an input visible our invisible you can use the hide/show functions http://api.jquery.com/hide/